# Not able to add any third party dependencies in android studio

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to add the below volley and aws dependencies throws below errors

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for

> ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1.

Android studio version 3.3.2, But works in older than 3 version

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1,
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.14'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.14'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.+',
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.6.14'
```

Comment: You are missing an ending single quote after implementation of volley library. It should be like this  `implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'`

Comment: you missed the closing quote for volley

Comment: also remove  comma `,` after `compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.+'`

Comment: Same error after adding below dependencies

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.14'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.14'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.+'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.6.14'

Comment: Would you please share your full both build.gradle file?

Comment: @venugopal Would you please try to `Invalidate Caches / Restart`.

Comment: post application gradle

Comment: buildscript {
    
    repositories {

        jcenter()
  google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
//        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

         jcenter()
  google()


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
            }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
       ----
                    }
        release {
            ----
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.0-alpha1"
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}

Comment: @venugopal Please update all support library to `28.0.0` instead of using `26.0.0-alpha1`. And also update the targetSdkVersion to 28.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

```
implementation "com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1"
implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.14"
implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.14"
implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.+"
implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.6.14"
```

Comment: is the same issue persist?